# iOS Swift IBKS Beacons error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, iphone, storyboard

[image: preview]

As you can see when clicking on the button "Notifications" or "IBKS Settings", the program stucks in the error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Sorry if this is a noob question but this is Swift and I'm new to this language.

Any help or hint to solve this issue?

Comment: Isn't the answer in the lower right corner of Xcode, in the error message? :)

Comment: That was the answer. Ohhhh!! (Facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Edit info.plist and add those String keys...And all right! It works!